# R shiny - Combine the slider bar with a text input to make the slider bar more user-friendly

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

When I try to select the range that has a extremely huge gap(such as 2000), it will be a little bit difficult for me to make a small step forward using the build-in sliderInput (such as adding 10 to the input). I am trying to implement two textInputs to interact with the sliderBar to control the min and max values to be more accurate on the same time. Are there some possible ways to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wuld recommend using the functions `updateSliderInput` and `updateTextInput` for that. Those functions let you update the given Values elements like this

```
updateSliderInput(session, "slider_id", value = c(0,1))
updateTextInput(session, "text_id", placeholder = "placeholder")
```

Alternatively, you can also use `renderUI`, but in most usecases, the update-functions are should be preferred for performance reasons.

The working solution below creates shiny module called `controledSlider`. This module takes `min`, `max` and `value` as an argument and displays a slider, two text boxes and an actionbutton.

```
library(shiny)

controlledSliderUI <- function(id){
  ns = NS(id)
  wellPanel(
    sliderInput(ns("slider"), NULL, 0, 1, c(0, 1)),
    textInput(ns("min"), "min", 0, "50%"),
    textInput(ns("max"), "max", 100, "50%"),
    actionButton(ns("update"), "update slider")
  )
}

controlledSlider <- function(input, output, session, min, max, value){
  reactiveRange <- reactiveValues(min = value[1], max = value[2])
  updateSliderInput(session, "slider", min = min, max = max)

  ## observe slider
  observeEvent(input$slider,{
    reactiveRange$min <- input$slider[1]
    reactiveRange$max <- input$slider[2]
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

  ## observe button
  observeEvent(input$update,{reactiveRange$min <- as.numeric(input$min)})
  observeEvent(input$update,{reactiveRange$max <- as.numeric(input$max)})

  ## observe reactive
  observeEvent({reactiveRange$min; reactiveRange$max},{
    updateSliderInput(
      session, "slider", value = c(reactiveRange$min, reactiveRange$max))
    updateTextInput(session, "min", value = reactiveRange$min)
    updateTextInput(session, "max", value = reactiveRange$max)
  })

  return(reactiveRange)
}
```

The module returns a `reactiveValue` object that can be read and updated from the main server function.

```
shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    controlledSliderUI("mySlider"),
    verbatimTextOutput("text")
  ),
  function(input, output, session){
    range <- callModule(controlledSlider, "mySlider", 0, 1200, c(100,1000))
    range$max <- 1001  ## update max
    output$text <- renderPrint({
      print(range$min)
      print(range$max)
    })
  }
)
```

[image]

Comment: I wish there was a way to click either slider and a text input would appear, accept the provided value, then adjust accordingly. Probably need some fancy js for that feature, but would be a major improvement and cleaner look IMO.