# How to update slider range using text input in Shiny? (currently gives back Error: Result must have length 10, not 0)

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, slider

I am creating a shiny app to analyze data in a database. I have set up a slider bar to select a range of values and also have two input boxes to adjust the range on the sliders.

In my simplified code below, the slider works fine, but when you try to update the slider by inputting numbers, I get the following error:

`Error: Result must have length 10, not 0`

The slider itself still works fine and does what it should in tandem with the selectInput, but as soon as you try to input a number into min or max and hit update, it gives back this error.

Looking online it seems this might be a problem with dplyr/filter(), but I couldn't really find any solutions for my problem and I'm not really sure if that's actually the problem here.

Below is some simplified code with some dummy data. For the slider, I am using the code found here to update the values: [R shiny - Combine the slider bar with a text input to make the slider bar more user-friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46776538/r-shiny-combine-the-slider-bar-with-a-text-input-to-make-the-slider-bar-more-u)

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

#Fake Data
 MSGRAIN <- data.frame("Year" = c(2018,2018,2018,2017,2016,2010,2010,2000,2000,2000), 
                       "SiteNameNew" = c('A','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','D','D'), 
                       "RiverMile" = 550:559)


ui <- fluidPage(
  # Selection Bar
  fluidRow(

    #Select by River Mile (Manual Input)
    column(5,
           controlledSliderUI('RiverMile')
           ),
    #Select By Site
    column(5,
           selectInput("SiteNameNew",
                       "Site Name:",
                       c("All", unique(as.character(MSGRAIN$SiteNameNew))
                         )
                       )
           ),
    column(6,h4(textOutput('test'))
           ),

    #Create a new row for the table
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  range <- callModule(controlledSlider, "RiverMile", 550, 559, c(550,559)
  )
  range$max <- 559

  # Current Year
  cyear <- as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))

  # Output to show if selected area has been tested in the last 5 years
  output$test <- renderText({
    data <- MSGRAIN %>%
      filter(SiteNameNew == input$SiteNameNew,
             RiverMile >= range$min,
             RiverMile <= range$max

      )

    if (max(data$Year) >= cyear-5){
      "This site has been tested in the last 5 years."
    } else if (max(data$Year) <= cyear-5){
      "This site has not been tested in the last 5 years."
    } else {
      "Cannot Determine"
    }
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    data <- MSGRAIN

    # Sorts data based on Site Name selected
    if (input$SiteNameNew !="All"){
      data <- data[data$SiteNameNew == input$SiteNameNew,]
    }
    # Sorts data based on River Mile selected
    if (range !="All"){
      data <- data[data$RiverMile >= range$min & data$RiverMile <= range$max,]
    }

    # Show Data Table
    data
    })
    )
}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I think it might be a combination of the code from the link + my code causing the issue, but I am new to shiny and not really sure where things are going wrong. I only have a pretty general understanding of how the observeEvent code is working to update my slider.

Comment: `Error in force(ui) : object 'ui' not found` I can't start your app. Why are you using modules?

Comment: Did you run the code in the link first? It gives you two new functions that I use in this code.

Comment: try dplyr::filter, perhaps the filter function is masked by another package

Comment: I copied your codes and updated the slider as *min=556*, *max=558*,It just worked fine! Did you copy `controlledSliderUI` and `controlledSlider` properly?

Comment: I'll try copying things over again. I had already tried that, but now that I'm thinking about it I may not have re-ran the code after copying again, so I'll see if that fixes things! Edit: It does work now on my sample code! Unfortunately, it still doesn't work on my full code, so it seems this is something I'll just have to figure out by going through the code again myself. Thanks!